# Debian 11 + ProFTPd and LDAPS

Tags: debian, ldap, proftpd

I'm trying to authenticate my FTP users from Active Directory using LDAPS over SSL (port 636).

I managed to get it working using simple LDAP on port 389 and now I would like to increase security!

OS is Debian 11 x64 up to date

ProFTPd version :

```
# dpkg -l | grep proftpd
ii  proftpd-core                   1.3.7a+dfsg-12+deb11u2         amd64        Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - binaries
ii  proftpd-mod-crypto             1.3.7a+dfsg-12+deb11u2         amd64        Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - TLS/SSL/SFTP modules
ii  proftpd-mod-ldap               1.3.7a+dfsg-12+deb11u2         amd64        Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - LDAP module
```

Here's the ldap.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ldap.c>
    LDAPServer                ldaps://x.x.x.x/??sub
    LDAPAuthBinds             on
    LDAPSearchScope           subtree
    LDAPBindDN                "CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "password"
    LDAPUsers                 "DC=domain,DC=local" "(&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))"
    LDAPGenerateHomedir       on 0775
    CreateHome                on 0755
    LDAPGenerateHomedirPrefix /home/ftphome
    LDAPDefaultUID            1111
    LDAPDefaultGID            1111
    LDAPAttr                  uid sAMAccountName
    LDAPAttr                  gidNumber primaryGroupID
    LDAPLog                   /var/log/proftpd/ldap.log
</IfModule>
```

When service is running (running as proftpd/nogroup), authentication is not working:

```
2023-05-23 14:54:19,616 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:54:19,618 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:54:19,619 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: attempting connection to URL ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/??sub
2023-05-23 14:54:19,620 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: set LDAP protocol version to 3
2023-05-23 14:54:19,629 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: bind as DN 'CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local' failed for 'ldaps://x.x.x.x/??sub': Can't contact LDAP server
2023-05-23 14:54:19,631 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:54:19,632 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:54:19,632 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: attempting connection to URL ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/??sub
2023-05-23 14:54:19,632 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: set LDAP protocol version to 3
2023-05-23 14:54:19,638 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21336]: bind as DN 'CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local' failed for 'ldaps://x.x.x.x/??sub': Can't contact LDAP server
```

I tried the debug mode ('proftpd -n -d 10') and it's working:

```
2023-05-23 14:56:51,051 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,053 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,054 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: attempting connection to URL ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/??sub
2023-05-23 14:56:51,055 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set LDAP protocol version to 3
2023-05-23 14:56:51,065 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: successfully bound as DN 'CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local' with password (see config) for 'ldaps://x.x.x.x/??sub'
2023-05-23 14:56:51,067 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set dereferencing to 0
2023-05-23 14:56:51,067 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set query timeout to 5 secs
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: searched under base DN DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute sAMAccountName
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute uidNumber
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute uidNumber, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using LDAPDefaultUID 1111
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute primaryGroupID
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute homeDirectory
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using default homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute loginShell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,194 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute loginShell, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,195 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: found user ftpuser1, UID 1111, GID 513, homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1, shell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,197 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,197 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,197 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: attempting connection to URL ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/??sub
2023-05-23 14:56:51,197 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set LDAP protocol version to 3
2023-05-23 14:56:51,207 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: successfully bound as DN 'CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local' with password (see config) for 'ldaps://x.x.x.x/??sub'
2023-05-23 14:56:51,207 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set dereferencing to 0
2023-05-23 14:56:51,207 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set query timeout to 5 secs
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: searched under base DN DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute sAMAccountName
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute uidNumber
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute uidNumber, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using LDAPDefaultUID 1111
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute primaryGroupID
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute homeDirectory
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using default homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute loginShell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute loginShell, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: found user ftpuser1, UID 1111, GID 513, homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1, shell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,323 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: searched under base DN DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute sAMAccountName
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute uidNumber
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute uidNumber, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using LDAPDefaultUID 1111
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute primaryGroupID
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute homeDirectory
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using default homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute loginShell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute loginShell, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: found user ftpuser1, UID 1111, GID 513, homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1, shell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: attempting connection to URL ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/??sub
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set LDAP protocol version to 3
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set dereferencing to 0
2023-05-23 14:56:51,404 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: set query timeout to 5 secs
2023-05-23 14:56:51,414 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter DC=domain,DC=local from template DC=domain,DC=local and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,414 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: generated filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) from template (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local)) and value ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,442 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: searched under base DN DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(sAMAccountName=ftpuser1)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local))
2023-05-23 14:56:51,442 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute sAMAccountName
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute uidNumber
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute uidNumber, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using LDAPDefaultUID 1111
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute primaryGroupID
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute homeDirectory
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: using default homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: fetching values for attribute loginShell
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: no values for attribute loginShell, trying defaults
2023-05-23 14:56:51,443 mod_ldap/2.9.5[21348]: found user ftpuser1, UID 1111, GID 513, homedir /home/domain/ftpuser1, shell
```

I don't understand why it runs OK in debug mode and of course I need it to run in service mode!
I tried running the service as root/root (which is bad!) and it's not working either.

Thanks for any help because I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make LDAP over SSL working but I managed to get LDAP over TLS working.
Not what I was looking for but better than unsecure connection!

```
<IfModule mod_ldap.c>
    LDAPServer                ldap://x.x.x.x/??sub ssl-verify:off
    LDAPUseTLS                on
    LDAPTLSRequireCert        off
    LDAPAuthBinds             on
    LDAPSearchScope           subtree
    LDAPBindDN                "CN=myuser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "password"
    LDAPUsers                 "DC=domain,DC=local" "(&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=FTP Users,CN=Users,OU=domain,DC=domain,DC=local))"
    LDAPGenerateHomedir       on 0775
    CreateHome                on 0755
    LDAPGenerateHomedirPrefix /home/domain
    LDAPDefaultUID            1111
    LDAPDefaultGID            1111
    LDAPAttr                  uid sAMAccountName
    LDAPAttr                  gidNumber primaryGroupID
    LDAPLog                   /var/log/proftpd/ldap.log
</IfModule>
```

Comment: currently SSL is deprecated, specially on WWW. This touch other services. Preferred negotiation is currelntly TLSv1.2 and v1.3 . Older TLS v1.1 and v1 (v1.0) are deprecated as SSL. Unfortunately many custom client based on java ftp modules, still uses SSL and old TLS versions. It should be upgraded. Problem is, not all companies have active support for that custom applications.